# Error when trying to change Word Document to different Content Type

Tags: content-type, word

I have some code that creates a new Word document in a Document Set and then I want to set the Content Type to be a custom type inheriting from document that I have created.

```
var newLetter = item.Folder.Files.Add("filename.docx", memStr, true);
newLetter.Item["ContentTypeID"] = library.ContentTypes[FieldValues.ContentType.Letter].Id;
```

I am getting the following error:

> Column 'ContentTypeID' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.

I'm doing the same thing with a TXT file in the same library and it works. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Is this using CSOM?

Comment: @AmalHashim I don't think so, it is server object model (SPWeb, etc)

Comment: Can you try with newLetter.ListItemAllFields["ContentTypeID"] ...

Comment: @Naim Didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by setting the content type at item creation by adding a `properties` Hashtable to my `Add` call, and setting the `ContentTyeID` in said `properties`.

I think there is still some underlying issue with not being able to change content types of documents that is also affecting the out of the box edit form.